# redirect all www to non www-site except for one site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have few sites running on my server. I want all site to change from www to non-www except one site `www.abc-xyz.org`. So I have written specific rule first then generic one. but its not working. when I am trying to open `www.abc-xyz.org` in browser it goes in some infinite loop.

my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc-xyz\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc-xyz.org/$1 [R=301,L]

#Generic redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is as expected, as the page keeps on loading. What you want to do is drop the first redirect, and add a "not" condition in the second.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.abc-xyz\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```